# VBA Interface implementing an Interface

Tags: vba, function, interface, polymorphism, signature

Is it possible to make the following work?

With `interface1.cls`

```
Public Sub X()
End Sub
```

And `interface2.cls`

```
Implements interface1

Public Sub interface1_X()
End Sub
```

To make `class1.cls`

```
Implements interface2
```

??

The following does not work:

```
Public Sub interface2_interface1_X()
End Sub
```

And VBA tells me that `class1` does not implement `interface1_X()`  of `interface2` .

So how do I make `class1`  implement `interface2` ? Is it even possible? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: If you could do that, what would be the point? You don't inherit implementation of `interface1_X` from `interface2`, you only sign a contract to provide a method with that signature. There is no class inheritance in VBA.

Comment: @GSerg I would like to make sure that every class implementing `interface2` also adds the functionality of `interface1` so that when I receive something that implements `interface2` somewhere else I can be sure I can use the functionality of `interface1`.

Comment: You cannot do that. Or rather you can, by repeating the methods of interface1 in interface2.

Comment: @Gserg oh well too bad but thanks for your reply! :)

Answer (score -1):

Off the top my head you can simulate inheritance in VBA using inheritance by composition. When get some time will flesh out an example.  See Rubberduck [OOP VBA pt.1: Debunking Stuff](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2016/06/16/oop-vba-pt-1-debunking-stuff/) and [OOP Battleship](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Battleship) [OOP Battleship Part 1: The Patterns](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/08/28/oop-battleship-part-1-the-patterns/) . Hopefully those blogs and code example will help.

If those don't help spefically to the question there more Rubber blogs on Interfaces and OPP.